# Routing /api endpoints to EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I am currently routing [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) to my CloudFront distribution to server the frontend.

How can I point the /api endpoint to the load balancer? I tried created a new hosted zone in the for example.com/api but my /api endpoints seem to still be hitting CloudFront.

Answer (score 0):

Route53 is a DNS service. DNS only handles translating hostnames to IP addresses. DNS does not handle the path portion of a URL in any way. The `/api` part of the URL is never even sent to Route53.

It's entirely unclear what you mean when you say you created a new hosted zone for the `/api` path.

The solution to your problem is to configure your load balancer as a second origin in your CloudFront distribution, and configure CloudFront to route `/api` requests to that origin.